# Concurrent hash map implementation with Go's channels

Tags: go, concurrency

I've implemented a concurrent hash map in Go. I'm fairly new to this language as I have mostly Python background so I'm looking for suggestions how to improve my code. I've ran the tests with `--race` and there weren't any reported issues but I'm not entirely sure that data races / deadlocks are not possible. Also, I had to duplicate `get/Get`, `set/Set`, etc. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
// Package cmap provides an implementation of HashMap and 
// ConcurrentMap, implemented using channels

package cmap

const (
    LoadFactorExpand = 0.75
    LoadFactorShrink = 1 - LoadFactorExpand
    InitialSize      = 16
    BigPrime1        = 100043
    BigPrime2        = 100151
    BigPrime3        = 1000000000039
)

const (
    MapRequestGet = iota
    MapRequestSet
    MapRequestDel
    MapRequestValues
)

type Key interface {
    Eq(Key) bool
    Hash() uint64
}

type IntKey int
type StringKey string

func (a IntKey) Eq(b Key) bool {
    return a == b
}

func (a IntKey) Hash() uint64 {
    var h uint64
    b := uint64(a)
    for ; b > 0; b /= 10 {
        h += ((b%10)*BigPrime1 + b*BigPrime2) % BigPrime3
    }
    return h
}

func (a StringKey) Eq(b Key) bool {
    return a == b
}

func (a StringKey) Hash() uint64 {
    var h uint64
    for _, c := range a {
        h += (uint64(c) + (h*BigPrime2)%BigPrime1) % BigPrime3
    }
    return h
}

type LinkedList struct {
    k    Key
    v    interface{}
    tail *LinkedList
}

func MakeLinkedList() *LinkedList {
    return &LinkedList{}
}

// getPrevElem returns the previous element which contains k in its tail.
// It returns (last element of the list, false) if k is not in the list
func (l *LinkedList) getPrevElem(k Key) (*LinkedList, bool) {
    var head *LinkedList
    for head = l; head.tail != nil; head = head.tail {
        if head.tail.k.Eq(k) {
            return head, true
        }
    }
    return head, false
}

func (l *LinkedList) Get(k Key) (interface{}, bool) {
    prev, ok := l.getPrevElem(k)
    if !ok {
        return nil, false
    }
    return prev.tail.v, true
}

func (l *LinkedList) Del(k Key) bool {
    prev, ok := l.getPrevElem(k)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    prev.tail = prev.tail.tail
    return true
}

func (l *LinkedList) Add(k Key, v interface{}) {
    var head *LinkedList
    for head = l; head.tail != nil; head = head.tail {
    }
    head.tail = &LinkedList{
        k: k,
        v: v,
    }
}

type KeyValue struct {
    k Key
    v interface{}
}

func (l *LinkedList) Values() []KeyValue {
    s := make([]KeyValue, 0)
    if l == nil {
        return s
    }
    for q := l.tail; q != nil; q = q.tail {
        s = append(s, KeyValue{k: q.k, v: q.v})
    }
    return s
}

type HashMap struct {
    buckets []*LinkedList
    size    int
}

func NewHashMap() *HashMap {
    return &HashMap{
        buckets: make([]*LinkedList, InitialSize, InitialSize),
        size:    0,
    }
}

func getBucketIndex(k Key, buckets []*LinkedList) uint64 {
    return k.Hash() % uint64(len(buckets))
}

func addValToBuckets(k Key, v interface{}, buckets []*LinkedList) {
    bucketIndex := getBucketIndex(k, buckets)
    l := buckets[bucketIndex]
    if l == nil {
        l = MakeLinkedList()
        buckets[bucketIndex] = l
    }
    prev, found := l.getPrevElem(k)
    if !found {
        prev.tail = &LinkedList{k: k, v: v}
    } else {
        prev.tail.v = v
    }
}

func (m *HashMap) rehash(newBuckets []*LinkedList) {
    for _, bucket := range m.buckets {
        if bucket == nil {
            continue
        }
        for q := bucket.tail; q != nil; q = q.tail {
            addValToBuckets(q.k, q.v, newBuckets)
        }
    }
}

func (m *HashMap) resize(newSize int) {
    newBuckets := make([]*LinkedList, newSize, newSize)
    m.rehash(newBuckets)
    m.buckets = newBuckets
}

func (m *HashMap) expand() {
    m.resize(len(m.buckets) * 2)
}

func (m *HashMap) shrink() {
    m.resize(len(m.buckets) / 2)
}

func (m *HashMap) load() float64 {
    return float64(m.size) / float64(len(m.buckets))
}

func (m *HashMap) Set(k Key, v interface{}) {
    if m.load() > LoadFactorExpand {
        m.expand()
    }
    m.size++
    addValToBuckets(k, v, m.buckets)
}

func (m *HashMap) Get(k Key) (interface{}, bool) {
    bucketIndex := getBucketIndex(k, m.buckets)

    if m.buckets[bucketIndex] == nil {
        return nil, false
    }

    return m.buckets[bucketIndex].Get(k)
}

func (m *HashMap) Del(k Key) bool {
    bucketIndex := getBucketIndex(k, m.buckets)

    if m.buckets[bucketIndex] == nil {
        return false
    }

    val := m.buckets[bucketIndex].Del(k)
    m.size--
    mLen := len(m.buckets)
    if m.load() < LoadFactorShrink && mLen > InitialSize {
        m.shrink()
    }
    return val
}

func (m *HashMap) Values() []KeyValue {
    s := make([]KeyValue, 0)
    for _, bucket := range m.buckets {
        s = append(s, bucket.Values()...)
    }
    return s
}

type mapResponse struct {
    v      interface{}
    ok     bool
    values []KeyValue
}

type mapRequest struct {
    mapRequestType int
    k              Key
    v              interface{}
    response       chan mapResponse
}

// Clients of ConcurrentMap should call Close
type ConcurrentMap struct {
    requests chan mapRequest
    m        *HashMap
}

func NewConcurrentMap() *ConcurrentMap {
    m := &ConcurrentMap{
        m:        NewHashMap(),
        requests: make(chan mapRequest),
    }
    go m.Serve()
    return m
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) get(k Key) mapResponse {
    v, ok := m.m.Get(k)
    return mapResponse{
        v:  v,
        ok: ok,
    }
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) set(k Key, v interface{}) mapResponse {
    m.m.Set(k, v)
    return mapResponse{
        ok: true,
    }
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) del(k Key) mapResponse {
    ok := m.m.Del(k)
    return mapResponse{
        ok: ok,
    }
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) values() mapResponse {
    values := m.m.Values()
    return mapResponse{
        values: values,
    }
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) Get(k Key) (interface{}, bool) {
    responseChan := make(chan mapResponse)
    go func() {
        m.requests <- mapRequest{
            mapRequestType: MapRequestGet,
            response:       responseChan,
            k:              k,
        }
    }()
    response := <-responseChan
    return response.v, response.ok
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) Set(k Key, v interface{}) {
    responseChan := make(chan mapResponse)
    go func() {
        m.requests <- mapRequest{
            mapRequestType: MapRequestSet,
            response:       responseChan,
            k:              k,
            v:              v,
        }
    }()
    <-responseChan
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) Del(k Key) bool {
    responseChan := make(chan mapResponse)
    go func() {
        m.requests <- mapRequest{
            mapRequestType: MapRequestDel,
            response:       responseChan,
            k:              k,
        }
    }()
    response := <-responseChan
    return response.ok
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) Values() []KeyValue {
    responseChan := make(chan mapResponse)
    go func() {
        m.requests <- mapRequest{
            mapRequestType: MapRequestValues,
            response:       responseChan,
        }
    }()
    response := <-responseChan
    return response.values
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) Serve() {
    for req := range m.requests {
        switch req.mapRequestType {
        case MapRequestGet:
            req.response <- m.get(req.k)
        case MapRequestSet:
            req.response <- m.set(req.k, req.v)
        case MapRequestDel:
            req.response <- m.del(req.k)
        case MapRequestValues:
            req.response <- m.values()
        default:
            panic("Unrecognized map request")
        }
    }
}

func (m *ConcurrentMap) Close() {
    close(m.requests)
}
```

In addition these are the tests:

```
package cmap

import (
    "testing"
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

func assertTrue(cond bool, t *testing.T, message string, args ...interface{}) {
    assertFalse(!cond, t, message, args...)
}

func assertFalse(cond bool, t *testing.T, message string, args ...interface{}) {
    if cond {
        t.Errorf(message, args...)
    }
}

func TestNewLinkedList(t *testing.T) {
    l := MakeLinkedList()

    l.Add(IntKey(1), "l1")
    l.Add(IntKey(2), "l2")
    l.Add(IntKey(3), "l3")
    l.Add(IntKey(4), "l4")
    l.Add(IntKey(5), "l5")
    l.Add(IntKey(6), "l6")
    l.Add(IntKey(7), "l7")

    var (
        s  interface{}
        ok bool
    )

    s, ok = l.Get(IntKey(1))
    assertTrue(ok && s.(string) == "l1", t, "Expected (\"l1\", true), received (%v, %v)", s, ok)

    s, ok = l.Get(IntKey(3))
    assertTrue(ok && s.(string) == "l3", t, "Expected (\"l3\", true), received (%v, %v)", s, ok)

    s, ok = l.Get(IntKey(15))
    assertFalse(ok, t, "Expected (nil, false), received (%v, %v)", s, ok)

    ok = l.Del(IntKey(1))
    assertTrue(ok, t, "Expected key 1 to be in the list")

    ok = l.Del(IntKey(1))
    assertFalse(ok, t, "Expected key 1 not to be in the list")

    s, ok = l.Get(IntKey(1))
    assertFalse(ok, t, "Expected (nil, false), received (%v, %v)", s, ok)

    l.Del(IntKey(5))
    l.Del(IntKey(7))
    l.Del(IntKey(3))

    expected := []KeyValue{
        {IntKey(2), "l2"},
        {IntKey(4), "l4"},
        {IntKey(6), "l6"},
    }

    values := l.Values()
    assertTrue(reflect.DeepEqual(expected, values), t, "Expected(%v) != Values(%v)\n", expected, values)
}

func MedianBucket(m *HashMap) (int, int, int, float64) {
    filled, l, maxBucket := 0, 0, 0
    for _, bucket := range m.buckets {
        if bucket != nil {
            filled++
            q := len(bucket.Values())
            if q > maxBucket {
                maxBucket = q
            }
            l += len(bucket.Values())
        }
    }
    return len(m.buckets), filled, maxBucket, float64(l) / float64(filled)
}

func TestHashMapBucketingInt(t *testing.T) {
    m := NewHashMap()
    var (
        numBuckets    int
        filled        int
        maxBucket     int
        averageBucket float64
    )

    l := 10000

    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        m.Set(IntKey(i), i)
    }

    t.Logf("IntKey")
    numBuckets, filled, maxBucket, averageBucket = MedianBucket(m)
    t.Logf("Number of buckets: %d; filled rows: %d; load: %f; maxBucket: %d; average items in bucket: %f",
        numBuckets, filled, m.load(), maxBucket, averageBucket)

    for i := l - 1; i >= 1000; i-- {
        m.Del(IntKey(i))
    }

    numBuckets, filled, maxBucket, averageBucket = MedianBucket(m)
    t.Logf("Number of buckets: %d; filled rows: %d; load: %f; maxBucket: %d; average items in bucket: %f",
        numBuckets, filled, m.load(), maxBucket, averageBucket)
}

func TestHashMapBucketingString(t *testing.T) {
    m := NewHashMap()
    var (
        numBuckets    int
        filled        int
        maxBucket     int
        averageBucket float64
    )

    l := 10000

    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        k := StringKey(fmt.Sprintf("%d", i))
        m.Set(k, i)
    }

    t.Logf("StringKey")
    numBuckets, filled, maxBucket, averageBucket = MedianBucket(m)
    t.Logf("Number of buckets: %d; filled rows: %d; load: %f; maxBucket: %d; average items in bucket: %f",
        numBuckets, filled, m.load(), maxBucket, averageBucket)

    for i := l - 1; i >= 1000; i-- {
        k := StringKey(fmt.Sprintf("%d", i))
        m.Del(k)
    }

    numBuckets, filled, maxBucket, averageBucket = MedianBucket(m)
    t.Logf("Number of buckets: %d; filled rows: %d; load: %f; maxBucket: %d; average items in bucket: %f",
        numBuckets, filled, m.load(), maxBucket, averageBucket)
}

func TestHashMapSetGetDel(t *testing.T) {
    var (
        v  interface{}
        ok bool
    )

    m := NewHashMap()

    l := 100
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        m.Set(IntKey(i), i)
    }

    v, _ = m.Get(IntKey(1))
    assertTrue(v == 1, t, "Get 1")

    v, _ = m.Get(IntKey(38))
    assertTrue(v == 38, t, "Get 38")

    v, _ = m.Get(IntKey(99))
    assertTrue(v == 99, t, "Get 99")

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        m.Del(IntKey(i))
        _, ok := m.Get(IntKey(i))
        assertFalse(ok, t, "Item %d is deleted", i)
    }

    for i := 11; i < 100; i++ {
        _, ok := m.Get(IntKey(i))
        assertTrue(ok, t, "Expected item %d", i)
    }

    m.Set(IntKey(1), 100)
    v, ok = m.Get(IntKey(1))
    assertTrue(ok && v == 100, t, "Expected item to be 100; got %d", v)
    m.Set(IntKey(1), 99)
    v, ok = m.Get(IntKey(1))
    assertTrue(ok && v == 99, t, "Expected item to be 99; got %d", v)
}

func TestHashMapValues(t *testing.T) {
    m := NewHashMap()
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        m.Set(IntKey(i), i)
    }
    for i := 95; i < 100; i++ {
        m.Del(IntKey(i))
    }
    for i := 90; i >= 0; i-- {
        m.Set(IntKey(i), 100-i)
    }

    expected := make([]KeyValue, 95)
    for i := 0; i < 91; i++ {
        expected[i] = KeyValue{IntKey(i), 100 - i}
    }
    for i := 91; i < 95; i++ {
        expected[i] = KeyValue{IntKey(i), i}
    }

    values := m.Values()
    sort.Slice(values, func(i, j int) bool {
        v1 := values[i].k.(IntKey)
        v2 := values[j].k.(IntKey)
        return v1 < v2
    })
    sort.Slice(expected, func(i, j int) bool {
        v1 := expected[i].k.(IntKey)
        v2 := expected[j].k.(IntKey)
        return v1 < v2
    })
    assertTrue(reflect.DeepEqual(expected, values), t, "\nExpected(%d):\n%v\nGot(%d):\n%v\n",
        len(expected), expected, len(values), values)
}

func TestConcurrentMapBombard(t *testing.T) {
    m := NewConcurrentMap()
    defer m.Close()

    l := 1000
    expected := make([]KeyValue, l)

    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        go func(v int) {
            m.Set(IntKey(v), v)
        }(i)
        expected[i] = KeyValue{IntKey(i), i}
    }

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    values := m.Values()
    sort.Slice(values, func(i, j int) bool {
        v1 := values[i].k.(IntKey)
        v2 := values[j].k.(IntKey)
        return v1 < v2
    })
    assertTrue(reflect.DeepEqual(expected, values), t, "\nExpected(%d):\n%v\nGot(%d):\n%v\n",
        len(expected), expected, len(values), values)
}

func TestNewHashMap(t *testing.T) {
    m := NewHashMap()
    if m.size != 0 || len(m.buckets) != InitialSize {
        t.Errorf("Hash Map m is not initialized")
    }
}
```

Comment: [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map), just in case you are not awared

Comment: One of the first issues is that you've implemented your buckets as a linked list. The native map type in go uses an array of buckets, which is really more efficient, instead of dereferencing a node on a list, find the next/previous, dereference again and repeat (pointer chasing). I'd just go for a simple struct type with a map + sync.RWMutex. I'd choose that over a `sync.Map`, too, because then at least your map can be typed